# Undeclared identifier when compiling with truffle compile

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, compiler

I have this contract and can't figure out where's the problem. Any ideas? (I'm a noob in solidity, just started a few days ago).

HelloWorld.sol file:

```
mapping (address => uint) balances;

function HelloWorld() {
    balances[msg.sender] = 1000;
}

function getBalance() public constant returns(uint) {
    return balances;
}

function sendCoin(address receiver, uint amount) public constant returns(bool sufficient) {
    if (balances[msg.sender] < amount) return false;

    balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
    balances[receiver] += amount;
    return true;
}
```

Moon.sol file:

```
mapping (address => uint) balances;

function Moon () {
    balances[tx.origin] = 1000;
}   

function getBalance() public constant returns(uint) {
    return balances;
}
```

In the Moon.sol file I missed out "mapping (address => uint) balances;".

Truffle compiler error:

```
$ truffle compile
Compiling .\contracts\HelloWorld.sol...
Compiling .\contracts\Moon.sol...

/C/Users/guerr/SmartContracs/firstPorject/contracts/Moon.sol:10:3: : 
Undeclared identifier.
            balances[tx.origin] = 1000;
            ^------^
Compiliation failed. See above.
```

Comment: Please paste the contents of the editor and terminal so the text is searchable/editable :)

Comment: Also the error appears to have occurred in `Moon.sol` rather than `HelloWorld.sol`, so the contents of that file (moon) are needed as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks okay but you should change `tx.origin` to `msg.sender` for security reasons. `tx.origin` is almost always an error.

I would get rid of that `moon.sol` file and try again.

Comment: Yes, my bad didn't even see that was the Moon.sol file generating the error :(